# Filter FK based on DateField

Tags: python, django, date, filter

I have a model, call it `A`, which has an FK relation to another model, call it `B`. `B` has a `DateField` we'll call `date`. I need to filter `A` based on the `date` field in the FK. 
I'm getting the date that I'm filtering based on as a string in the form `YYYY-MM-DD` (in a variable called `start`). The filtering is a greater than filter. I'm filtering a queryset called `results`, which has itself been filtered based on some other criteria.

Here's the code I have right now.

```
start=datetime.strptime(start, "%Y-%m-%d")
results.filter(B__date__gte=start)
```

Then something is done with `results`, however, nothing is being filtered. By which I mean the contents of `results` after the call above is always the same as that before.

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to filter this? I'm also doing a `lte` filter, but figured if I was able to solve one problem, I'd be able to solve the other.

Answer (score 0):

Oh god... I feel so stupid.

There was no assignment.

Should have been `results=results.filter(B__date__gte=start)`